# Saving a BigDecimal to a decimal field in the database makes BigDecimal different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point, bigdecimal

I always thought you should never use floats for saving money in the database. So i used decimal. The problem is i save a decimal 100 and it puts it in the database as 99.9999

I have a model named GameCommission

Migration:

```
create_table :game_commissions, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer :game_id
  t.integer :widget_id
  t.integer :user_id
  t.decimal :amount, :precision => 6, :scale => 4, :default => 0
  t.date :end_date
  t.timestamps
end
```

Now i make quickly a new GameCommission:

```
amount = BigDecimal.new("100")
gc = GameCommission.new(:game_id => 1, :widget_id => 1, :user_id => User.last.id, :amount => amount, :end_date => Date.today)
gc.save
gc.amount.to_s
# => "100
```

the amount is now 100 which is what i want. But if i fetch it again the amount changes to 99.9999 and that is also the amount that is saved in the database....

```
gc = GameCommission.last
gc.amount.to_s
# => "99.9999"
```

Somebody knows what is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the values `:precision => 6, :scale => 4` in your `:amount` field, causing `100` to be scaled down to `99.9999` as the 3 figures of 100 plus the 4 mandatory decimal places = 7, which is greater than 6.

`:precision => 6, :scale => 4` can store a number from `-99.9999 to 99.9999`, which is why 100 is being downscaled.

Change `:precision` to `7` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel kind of stupid :) I thought precision was before the comma and scale was after the comma but precision is indeed all number of the characters, before or after the comma. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<s>What's this `:amount` type you're using? According to the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column), there's no such thing, but there *is* a `:decimal` type, which sounds like it should solve the problem.</s>

Comment: I use the :decimal type. `t.decimal :amount`

Comment: Koper: ah, that's the shorthand notation; my lack of experience in rails shows. Then it could be a problem with the DB type mapping. What DB are you using?

Comment: hehe no problem :) I use mysql. I guess postgres would give me an error because i tried to save a 7 precision into a 6 precision column. @S1R had the right answer. Thanks anyways!